# C Program crashing on second use of a function

Tags: c, crash

Trying to make a program that reads formatted input from file and it crashes when it uses `Emmission_read()` a second time. If I comment out the loop it works fine.

```
void Top_read(FILE* f, TVNodeType head) {
    TVNodeType ptr;
    head = mallocwarp(sizeof(TVNodeType));
    head->next = NULL;
    ptr = head;
    int ekp, i;

    fscanf(f, "<%d>\n", &ekp);

    //Edw 3erw poses ekpompes exw kai 8a ftia3w ena struct gia tin ka8e mia

    Emmission_read(f, ptr->anEmmission);

    for (i = 1; i < ekp; i++) {
        ptr->next = mallocwarp(sizeof(TVNodeType));

        ptr = ptr->next;

        Emmission_read(f,ptr->anEmmission);
        ptr->next = NULL;
    }
    printf("%d Top read\n",ekp);
}
```

Everything works fine when I use `emmission_read` once. I don't think it is a `malloc_` problem nor a problem with another function.

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code in your debugger ?

Comment: I'm afraid it is a problem with `Emmission_read`.  Using a debugger, you can step through that function and see what does wrong.

Comment: Please post the definitions of `TVNodeType` and `Emmission_read`.

Answer (score 1):

From your code it appears that `TVNodeType` is a pointer type. Then your memory allocation should be `mallocwarp(sizeof(TVNodeType *));`

(Credits due to user3121023)